# Straightening Lines without Straightening Iron

Tags: modeling, snapping, mathematics

[image: No me gusta]

[image: Me gustaish]

Thanks for looking this over in advance.

Hopefully pictures describe this somewhat well- but I'm looking to take the guess out of my guesswork here and have lines which are "perfectly straight". Here, that means for Vertex A, B, C all on the same plane and collectively forming an Edge, with Vertex B at some point between the two others- the interior/exterior angles at Point/Vertex B are equal to 180 degrees.

Any thoughts on how to go about doing this?

In case there's a mixup, the second picture is simulating what I want to do, but that's going about it in the eyeballing way/guessing where co-linearity occurs.

Additionally I should mention that similar questions suggest scaling on an axis around a median point, which works great for lines which are perceptively straight up/down or left/right, but with this angled business the method does not appear to work as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a custom orientation.

1. Select the A and C vertices and choose a *Normal Orientation*
2. Click the + button to save this new orientation
3. Select vertices A + B + C (order matters) and set pivot point to *Active element*
4. Scale the selection to 0

*Making a custom orientation*
[image]

*Scaling to 0, active vertex as pivot point.*
[image]

Comment: Works like a gem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you :). Good luck with your project.